# If i extend a static class in PHP, and the parent class refers to "self::", will this refer to the self in the extended class?

Tags: php, class, static, extends

If i extend a static class in PHP, and the parent class refers to "self::", will this refer to the self in the extended class?

So, for example

```
<?php 
Class A
{
    static $var  
    public static function guess(){self::$var = rand(); return $var}
}        

Class B extends Class A
{
    public static function getVar(){return self::$var}
}
```

If I ran 
B::guess();
then B::getVar();

is the value for Var stored in A::$var or B::$var?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to test:

```
class ClassA {
    public static function test(){ self::getVar(); }
    public static function getVar(){ echo 'A'; }
}        

class ClassB extends ClassA {
    public static function getVar(){ echo 'B'; }
}

ClassA::test(); // prints 'A'

ClassB::test(); // also prints 'A'
```

... hope that helps :)

Answer (score 6):

[Late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) was introduced in PHP 5.3, it allows you to control this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Additional information, usage of self or $this is different into extended classes

```
class ClassA {
    public function test(){ self::getVar(); }
    public function test2(){ $this->getVar(); }
    
    public function getVar(){ echo 'A'; }
}        

class ClassB extends ClassA {
    public function getVar(){ echo 'B'; }
}

$classB = new ClassB();
$classB->test(); // prints 'A'
$classB->test2(); // prints 'B'
```